# Is cache entry refreshed on getIfPresent in com.google.common.cache?

Tags: caching

I am using `com.google.common.cache.Cache` class for caching implementation. My implementation sets 15 minutes for cache eviction time. So when I add a new entry it will be evicted from the cache after 15 minutes. What happens when I execute `getIfPresent` method for a specific cache entry? Will the eviction time for this entry renewed for another 15 minutes every time I call this method?

When I tried to look at the source code I am unable to come to a conclusion whether it renew the eviction time or not.

The version of the library: 32.1.2

Comment: `LocalCache.getIfPresent` calls `Segment.get` which in turn calls `scheduleRefresh` when the entry was found. If the entry's last write exceeds the refresh threshold duration, then the entry will be reloaded (optionally asynchronously). When reloaded that will set the write timestamp, thereby extending its lifetime.